# Getting "source output path is invalid" after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, files, permissions

We have a very puzzling error after upgrading a build server from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. An in-house developed tool suddenly starts failing with:

ERROR: source input path /local/mnt/workspace/dir-name/filename.xml is invalid.

There is no difference in the executable or the input files, and the same versions work on a different machine. If I copy the relevant files to my home directory and run the tool there, it works as normal, on the same machine. It is not a file permission issue, everything looks ok and the whole thing is part of a version controlled Git workspace. The input files are all in XML format and you can view / edit them as normal. So the application itself can for some reason not read a simple text file.

The executable is ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24. We already did apt-get install lsb but maybe some other package is missing?

It's a known good tool that has not been modified in a long time and same version works on other build machines.

Comment: It's an in-house tool. Have you asked the developer(s)?

Comment: The program that's giving the error message, was it launched before the filesystem on `/local/mnt` was mounted?

Comment: No, it's part of the build procedure long time after mounting.

Comment: Has filename.xml changed recently? Is it a valid xml file?  Is it what your in-house tool expects?   In other words, is your in-house tool complaining about the existence/accessibility of the file, or is it complaining that it's garbage?

Comment: are **ALL** directories in the path to filename.xml both readable **and** executable by the user id running your in-house tool?  maybe one of the parent dirs has had its permissions changed.

Comment: None of the files (executable and .xml) have changed in a long time. It's all under Git version control. Same executable works on a different server. I can run the executable successfully if I copy the .xml files from /local/mnt/workspace/xxx to my home dir. All file permissions are ok. Jenkins job run by that account gives same error.

Comment: You didn't answer the question - I was asking about **directory** permissions, not file permissions.  To be able to read a file, you need read permission on that file **AND** both read & execute permission on the directory it's in and all parent directories.   same for your in-house tool, the UID of that process needs at least read access on the file and read and execute on the directories.

Comment: We already checked the directory permissions, they are the same in the entire path as on a machine that works.